# Which Chrome tab or extension opened a browser tab?

Tags: google-chrome, popups

I'm seeing a spammy popup tab in Chrome.

How do I determine its origin, which might be another tab or an extension? I poked around in the console, e.g. `window.origin` and `window.history` but don't see any offenders.